# android binder using java aidl

Tags: java, android, android-source

In android IPC using binder, when we create an aidl file, build will automatically generate a stub class extending binder and override all the aidl methods right?.
In the service class implementation for the aidl methods , have seen instantiating the stub class generated instead of extending the stub class.Since stub class is abstract , how can it be instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

The question was generic related to interface instantiation. As we know interface can not be instantiated but code like below:

```
interface in = new in() {
    public void test(){
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

is possible as I am defining what the instance need to be done.